# Program using maximum memory in linux

Tags: linux, performance, kernel, perf, memory-access

Let's say , there are 3-4 highly memory intensive applications running in linux - for example,say, any video processing application. Those applications are using different amount of RAM and their memory access patterns are also different. Also, lets say, those applications are running in different cores.

Lets say all of these programs run for 5 seconds.

What I am trying to find -

1. Which functions among these applications using maximum memory at a particular instant? I need the name of first 2-3 functions which are taking maximum memory resource.
2. If multiple functions need a high amount of memory ( which is above a threshold limit) at the same instant, what are their names and how long they need that high amount of memory.

I need some help on this – Cant actually understand how to proceed. Will cache miss calculation using perf tool help? I am new in linux, please write with a little explanation. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Use Profiling, for memory take heapdumps at regular interval and analyze for finding methods which are taking most memory.

Comment: Could you please explain it in a little detail please - I am new in linux. @ Nachiket . If possible , give an example code etc

Answer (score 2):

You can use profilers, Heap analysis tools for getting cpu and memory util of each method.

**Profilers** are tools which will add some loggers/debug statements/custom code to your application code and will tell you time taken by each method,query in your application. This solves your first question i.e. you want most cpu taken by which method. A process which is running for longest duration is most likely utilizing most cpu. Profiler will show you those processes. After that you can analyze method by yourself by putting debug statements and loggers to drill down.

Programs are using memory for keeping objects, variables. You can find out which method/object is taking high memory by looking only at memory snapshot. You can get **heapdump or memory snapshot** (I am not sure about c,c++ code but probably there are tools, commands available). Once you get those snapshots analyze them for objects/methods occupying largest memory block.

After finding these culprits, try to improve them using better hw,sw, libraries, perf tunings etc.

I hope you are clear now :)

Answer (score 1):

You could use `ps` (perhaps with `watch`) or `top` or `htop` to look at memory consumption of processes. For example, if you have three [processes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_%28computing%29) of pid 1234, 2345, and 3456 ( you could find these pids using `ps|grep programname` or `pidof` or `pgrep` etc...) you might run

```
watch ps -F 1234 2345 3456
```

> Which functions among these applications using maximum memory at a particular instant?
>
> If multiple functions need a high amount of memory

I guess that you are speaking of C (or C++) functions in your code. Then both questions above don't have any sense: memory consumption is a *global* property of your program. When (and this happens often) a memory zone is allocated in one function (calling `malloc`), filled in another one, and released in yet another one (calling `free`) it does not have sense to say which function is owning that data or consuming that memory.

You might use [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) (at least to check that you don't leak memory).

Also notice that if your program calls `malloc` then `free` correctly, the freed memory is not always given back to the OS: most `malloc` implementations would try to "keep" `free`-d memory to be immediately reusable at *future* calls to `malloc`

Read the wikipages on [garbage collection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Garbage_collection_%28computer_science%29), on [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak) and on [memory management](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_management), in particular on [C dynamic memory allocation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_dynamic_memory_allocation). RTFM [malloc(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/malloc.3.html) & [mmap(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) (since `mmap` is used by `malloc`) & [proc(5)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man5/proc.5.html) (since `/proc/` can be used to query the memory map and state, use `cat /proc/$(pidof yourprogram)/maps` etc...) &  [setrlimit(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/setrlimit.2.html) (which enables you to limit, e.g. with the `ulimit` builtin of `bash`, the available memory) & [ps(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/ps.1.html) & [watch(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/watch.1.html) & [pgrep(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pgrep.1.html) & [pidof(1)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/pidof.1.html). Read also [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/)

Comment: Top,htop, ps doesn't give method wise cpu and memory usage. As per my knowledge :) User is asking for method wise usage.

Comment: How can I see in which instant how much memory individual function of the application is taking?

Comment: As I am trying to explain, your question does not make any sense.

Comment: Let me be more clear - I have two programs which are running parallelly and which access memory in a periodic pattern ( I know this part ). ( what I dont know )for example. at t=1, program A need 1000MB for 1 ms, at t=2, programB need 1000MB for 2 ms.  I need to find a way by which I can know the last part . From time t=1 to t=5, which program used how much memory at every second?